# Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501 when called inside of useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using React JS, Redux, React-
Redux
, Redux-Thunk.

File: Acions.js:
Here are my Redux Action functions:

```
export function setSuccess(data){
    return{
        type: "SET_SUCCESS",
        payload: data
    };
}


export function setMessage(data){
    return{
        type: "SET_POSTS",
        payload: data
    };
}


export const listMyBlogPosts = (userID, abortController) =>{

    return (dispatch) =>{
        axios.get(`http://locahost:5000/timeline/posts/${userID}`, {signal: abortController})
            .then((response) =>{
                dispatch(setSuccess(true));
                dispatch(setMessage(response.data.message));

            }).catch((error) =>{
                console.log("err: ", error);
                dispatch(setSuccess(false));
                dispatch(setMessage(`${error}`));
            });
    }

};
```

Here is where I am using the above function:

File: ABC.js:

```
function ABC({ someCheck }){
    const abortController = useRef(new AbortController()); 
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    console.log(“ABC component”);

    useEffect(() =>{
       
        navigation.addListener("focus", () =>{

            dispatch(listMyBlogPosts(userID, abortController.current.signal));
            
            console.log("focus is being run!");

        });

        return () => abortController.current.abort();

    }, []);   
    
}
```

In the ABC component, I get the following error:

[image: error message]

If I remove the useEffect hook, I do not get the above error ?

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is adding more and more event 'focus' listeners, which is leading to lots of request call. So you need to remove those event listener once component is unmounted.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const onFocus = () => {
    dispatch(listMyBlogPosts(userID, abortController.current.signal))
    console.log('focus is being run!')
  }
  navigation.addListener('focus', onFocus)

  return () => {
    navigation.removeListener('focus', onFocus)
    abortController.current.abort()
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: that didn’t resolve the error. Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: @Abc123 thats weird, how many time  ```'focus is being run!``` is being printed in console ?

Comment: it’s printed once. I put a  console.log(“ABC component”) statement inside of the ABC component, it gets printed multiple times. What might be the reason behind this?

Comment: @Abc123 thats expected, its because of react rendering. If ```'focus is being run``` is printed only once/twice and but you still facing excessive callbacks error I dont have answer. check your code thoroughly, you might missed somethings. if you want to see which one is calling your dispatch function, put [`console.trace('..somehting..')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/trace) just before calling `axios.get` function.